# Finding all occurrences of two datetimes in close proximity to each other (6 hours)

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I find ALL occurrences of two datetimes that are close to each other for the same member (among other criteria).  That is I have a table with a bunch of date times, and I'm looking to find any instances of two which are close together in time for the same member ID. Output would just be those two times that are close together, and the member ID.

Usually would provide some example, but have no idea how to approach this.

Database looks like:

```
+-----------+---------------------+
| MemberID  | datetime            |
+-----------+---------------------+
| John      | 2019-10-10 01:01:01 |
| John      | 2020-08-10 01:01:01 |
| John      | 2020-08-10 04:01:01 |
| John      | 2020-09-07 01:01:01 |
| Joe       | 2019-10-10 01:01:01 |
| Joe       | 2020-10-10 01:01:01 |
| Rich      | 2018-10-10 01:01:01 |
| Rich      | 2019-10-10 01:01:01 |
| Rich      | 2020-02-10 09:01:01 |
| Rich      | 2020-02-10 10:11:01 |
+-----------+---------------------+
```

Output would be (Only those rows which were close in time [within 6 hours of each other] for that MemberID

```
+-----------+---------------------+
| MemberID  | datetime            |
+-----------+---------------------+
| John      | 2020-08-10 01:01:01 |
| John      | 2020-08-10 04:01:01 |
| Rich      | 2020-02-10 09:01:01 |
| Rich      | 2020-02-10 10:11:01 |
+-----------+---------------------+
```

Update: Cannot us [lead](/questions/tagged/lead) or [lag](/questions/tagged/lag), [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) version is 5.X

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  What does "close in time" mean?

Comment: Within 6 hours of each other.  So any member ID which has two submissions within 6 hours of each other.  Will elaborate above.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `lag()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lag(dt) over (partition by member order by dt) as prev_dt
      from t
     ) t
where prev_dt > dt - interval 6 hour;
```

This requires MySQL 8+.  In earlier versions, you can use a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             (select max(t2.dt) 
              from t t2 
              where t2.member = t.member and
                    t2.dt < t.dt
             )  as prev_dt
      from t
     ) t
where prev_dt > dt - interval 6 hour;
```

Comment: Thanks for that, looks like that's a great lead.  Never used lag before, does something like this look right.  (syntax error)  [EDIT sorry, didn't realize comments aren't formatted.]  ----


SELECT `dispatch`.*


from (select `dispatch`.*,


             lag(`dispatch`.`sortdate`) over (partition by `dispatch`.`Member_no` order by `dispatch`.`sortdate`) as prev_dt
      from `dispatch`
     ) t
where t.prev_dt > `dispatch`.`sortdate` - interval 6 hour;

Comment: No idea what I'm doing wrong (not sure if LAG is not installed on my shared hosting?), the syntax seems right for the inner query:  (select `dispatch`.* , LAG(`sortdate`) over(PARTITION BY `Member_no` order by `sortdate`) as prevdt from `dispatch`;)  But it's saying An alias was previously found.

Comment: Apparently LEAD/LAG isn't installed on this server, is there any other way to accomplish this?